# Confusing Javascript issue validating form. Input field value works, but saving object of input field doesn't

Tags: javascript, object, input, field

Apologies for the unweildy title, this is a very difficult question to put into words. This code will explain it much better.

```
alert(formob.Nam.value); //i work correctly
alert(formob.Num.value); //and me  

name=formob.Nam; 
console.log(name); //[object HTMLInputElement]
console.log("name set "+name.value); //i return 'name set undefined'

num=formob.Num;
console.log(num); //<input type="text" name="Num">
console.log("num set "+num.value); //i return 'num set [value entered]' correctly
```

Simplified HTML:

```
<form method="post" class="well" name="FooterCall">
<input type="text" name="Nam">
<input type="text" name="Num">
<button... onmousedown="subajax(this.form...)"..>
```

Summary:
Two essentially identical fields are being set in a form, but one sets incorrectly when the field is set to a Javascript object.

Thankyou very much in advance for any help that can be offered! :)

Comment: a maybe stupid idea, but could it be that `name` is a reserved word in the window namespace?... try to use `nameInput` or something and then ask for `nameInput.value`

Comment: the name of the form in the html example should be `formob` (but this is not the problem)

Comment: @TobiasKrogh it is not stupid idea, that solves the problem http://jsfiddle.net/fGBGc/3/ post it as an answer before someone else :O

Comment: You guys are so awesome! :) Just to clear up the `formob`, the function receives `this.form` as variable `formob`, so it's not related to the form name in any way. As you said though, that wasn't the problem. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use the following HTML

```
<form method="post" name="formob">
<input type="text" name="Nam">
<input type="text" name="Num">
</form>
​
```

and check this JavaScript where you do not use `name`as variable name it should work imho. formob needs to be a reference to the form of course:

```
console.log(formob.Nam.value); //i work correctly
console.log(formob.Num.value); //and me  

xname = formob.Nam;
console.log(xname); //[object HTMLInputElement]
console.log("name set " + xname.value); //i return 'name set undefined'

num = formob.Num;
console.log(num); //<input type="text" name="Num">
console.log("num set " + num.value); //i return 'num set [value entered]' correctly​
```

this should work

Comment: Thankyou very much - really silly mistake that was driving me mad. Fixed it, thanks a load! :)

Comment: Somehow managed to miss that giant tick, done now. :) Cheers again!